# Customised text over an image

Tags: image, input, generator, textfield

Hi I'm looking for the user to add text in a field which will then be put over an image. Like the Christmas card generators online.
To explain this further please see image:

[image]

So there would be a '**Name**' or '**Title**' field (James Draper) and then a '**Description**' field (best...) for underneath.

It would be great if this could then be emailed.

Can anyone help out? Perhaps a tutorial link?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What programming language are you looking to use? Assuming that you want a web-based solution, what you want can be done with PHP's image functions.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understood your question, may be this can help (http://www.wikihow.com/Put-Text-on-Pictures)

Comment: or you can add this picture as background of the page and add text box  on the exact location so it will look like the text boxes are on the images ;)